# Can we get the Number Value of the list element in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, list

Are you able to display the element number value in a visualforce repeat. For eg:

```
<apex:repeat var="li" value="{!list}">
 <p>{!fieldOne}<p>
 <p>{!fieldTwo}<p>
 <p>list[0]<p> <--  How can I display 0 here?
</apex:repeat>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just output `Li` as it holds each value of `apex:repeat` iteration variable list

```
<apex:repeat var="li" value="{!list}">
 <p>{!fieldOne}<p>
 <p>{!fieldTwo}<p>
 <p>{!li}<p> <--  How can I display 0 here?
</apex:repeat>
```

**and if your intention is to display the index of the list then you do it using apex:variable**

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>

    <apex:repeat var="li" value="{!list}">
     <p>{!fieldOne}<p>
     <p>{!fieldTwo}<p>
     <p>{!rowNum}<p> <--  How can I display 0 here?
     <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: N.B. variables are not intended to be used in iterators, and may have undesirable side effects.

Comment: @sfdcfox, if you can post a better answer I will delete mine. The correct and accurate answer has to be accepted as it will get referred in the future as well

Comment: @RedDevil I gave you +1 anyways, but it's something you may want to avoid using in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The *officially supported* way is to use a wrapper class or a list of numbers.

## List of Indexes

```
<apex:repeat var="index" value="{!listIndexes}">
  <p>{!listVar[index]['fieldOne']}<p>
  <p>{!listVar[index]['fieldTwo']}<p>
  <p>{!index}<p>
</apex:repeat>
```

Where listIndexes might come from a method like this:

```
public Integer[] getListIndexes() {
  Integer size = listVar.size();
  Integer[] results = new Integer[size];
  for(Integer index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    results[index] = index;
  }
  return results;
}
```

## Wrapper

This is as simple as defining a wrapper for the list. You can even relatively seamlessly convert your wrapper on the fly as an accessor:

```
public class Wrapper {
  public Integer rowNum { get; set; }
  public SObject record { get; set; }
  public Wrapper(Integer rowNum, SObject record) {
    this.rowNum = rowNum;
    this.record = record;
  }
}
public Wrapper[] getWrappedItems() {
  Integer size = listVar.size();
  Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[size];
  for(Integer index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    results[index] = new Wrapper(index, listVar[index]);
  }
  return results;
}
```

This results in the following Visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat var="wrapper" value="{!wrappedItems}">
  <p>{!wrapper.record.field1}<p>
  <p>{!wrapper.record.field2}<p>
  <p>{!wrapper.rowNum}<p>
</apex:repeat>
```